# Google Cloud Datastore from embedded device in POSIX c?

Tags: c, embedded, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I managed to get Google Cloud Messaging working on an embedded device using libcurl using http requests and a 'BrowserKey' for authentication.
Now i would like to move to Google Cloud Datastore for saving settings of the embedded device into the cloud. There seems to be support for Java, Ruby, Python, NodeJS but so far I found nothing that could help me further using things i know.

Can I get access to the Cloud Datastore from my existing application written in plain C ?

Answer (score 0):

While we don't have client libraries for C, we do have a RESTful API ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/reference/rest/)) that you can call, so it should be possible to write your own simple library in C to talk to Cloud Datastore from an embedded device.

If you are concerned about security (since someone could possibly impersonate your embedded device and get direct access to your Cloud Datastore instance, I recommend you take a look at Cloud Endpoints ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/)). It gives you an easy way to generate a RESTful API on top of App Engine. You could then use your custom API in the embedded device and use App Engine as a proxy/data validation layer that controls access to the database.